# Linking bokeh plot with images

Tags: python, plot, bokeh

I have had great success plotting GPS from drone flights using bokeh and displaying other data using its hover ability. I am now looking to enhance my plots by allowing the user to click on a data point frpm the plot and display an image (currently .bmp but others are possible) from the flight video. Does bokeh have this functionality? I have been searching for quite some time and haven't been able to make any headway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This [Bokeh Google Group discussion](https://groups.google.com/a/continuum.io/forum/#!msg/bokeh/d1d37KkGyTs/I8hevSgaHaEJ) explains the development that is going on right now for this functionality.